# Capturing a Click on a NativeWindow

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, .net-4.0

I have a class based on the NativeWindow class and I want to be able to perform some action when the user clicks inside of it. Here is what I tried:

*Code removed*

However it doesn't work. Debugging suggests for some reason the message is never 0x0201 which is supposedly a left mouse button click. What's wrong with it?

Comment: Have you tried overriding `DefWndProc`? You'll need to use the `new` keyword.

Comment: How do you instantiate from the MessageTool class?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud Where would the `new` fit in exactly?

Comment: @SimonMourier What do you mean?

Comment: How do you create an instance of this class?

Comment: @StickFigs, you'll need to define the method like `new public void DefWndProc(ref Message m)` so that it hides the base implementation.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud I tried replacing `protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)` with `new public void DefWndProc(ref Message m)` and `base.WndProc(ref m);` with `base.DefWndProc(ref m);` but debugging shows unlike WndProc the DefWndProc function is never even entered while using the program.

Comment: @StickFigs, sorry friend.

Comment: Silly question but have you assigned the correct handle to the class? Everything else looks in order.

Comment: @Rotem - yeah... hence my question 1h ago :-)

Comment: Your previous question about this code showed that you are swallowing exceptions in this method.  Bad idea to not mention that.  The odds that messages just disappear without trace are of course great.  I'd furthermore guess that the window you are trying to wrap is owned by a different process.  That's not possible.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @Rotem What do you mean by the correct handle?

Comment: I mean have you made sure that the window you are assigning to the `NativeWindow` instance is the window that gets the `WM_LMOUSEDOWN` messages. Also see Hans' comment for possible thing that are wrong. Either way, post more code, otherwise it's just guesswork.

Comment: @SimonMourier Added instantiation code to the question.

Comment: NativeWindow is typically used for creating an instance of a system defined dialog/window, or subclassing an existing window.  Is thise your use case or are you trying to do something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure tooltips can receive a WM_LBUTTONDOWN. You could try using the [TTM_RELAYEVENT message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760403%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that's meant for passing a mouse message to a tooltip control for processing, something like this:

```
    protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
    {
        const int TTM_RELAYEVENT = 0x407;
        if (m.Msg == TTM_RELAYEVENT)
        {
            Message relayed = (Message)Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, typeof(Message));
            if (related.Msg == WM_LBUTTONDOWN)
            {
                // Do something
            }
        }

        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

Comment: Windows Tooltips are very tricky beasts to play with if you want specialties. Sometimes, its better to roll your own (not that easy either).